# Some troubles with .htaccess regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Hi I am trying to make a .htaccess using the rewrite engine but I can't find the regular expresion to make it work and actually I have been struggled with it for some days. So I Have 2 types of php files some look like:

- list.php
- users.php

and other pages with 1 parameter, allways with the same name

- user.php?p=1
- action.php?p=1

All of them are inside the same folder:
localholst/my_dir/admin/

So I want to make a RewriteRule to do the following:

- localholst/my_dir/admin/actions  =>
  localholst/my_dir/admin/actions.php
- localholst/my_dir/admin/user/1      =>
  localholst/my_dir/admin/user.php?p=1

My .htaccess is now:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that in `.htaccess` in your `admin/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ user.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.